# docker image not working or running properly

Tags: api, docker, asp.net-core

This is part of a major issue i've been fighting to get resolve in a span of 2 or even 3 weeks, first of all, i'm not a docker expert, in fact, i don't even know a thing about docker, all i know is that i need to use it in order to make a connection between an api in localhost and my app in react native, the thing is, i manage to make it work on another two projects i created to test docker, but not in the one i actually need to. This is a dockerfile for an api in .net core 2.2

my dockerfile is a combination of the code i found in stackoverflow and the example in docker documentation to create a docker in .net core, this specific file worked for me on another two api, one as a blank project, and the other one with a class library.

The code below shows the dockerfile, when i run the command line and create the image, it shows no errors, but i know there is something wrong, because when i run docker image ls, the docker image is around 200-300mb size, which seems way too small, and when i run that image with docker run... and check the list of docker containers runnning, it shows nothing

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
WORKDIR /src
COPY ISARRHH.sln ./
COPY ISARRHH.BusinessGraph/*.csproj ./ISARRHH.BusinessGraph/
COPY ISARRHH.APIWeb/*.csproj ./ISARRHH.APIWeb/
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
WORKDIR /src/ISARRHH.BusinessGraph
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

WORKDIR /src/ISARRHH.APIWeb
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "isarrhh.dll"]

#######################################################
```

I want this bloody docker to work, this was the plan b on one of the modules i'm working on, and is giving me a headache, i managed to make it work on another project, i want it to work on this api which works with office 365 and sharepoint

EDIT: this is the project structure

```
ISARRHH (Solution)
|
|--ISARRHH.APIWeb (API)
|  |_Dependencies
|  |_Controllers
|  |_Models
|  |_Properties
|  |_appsettings.json
|  |_appsettings.Development.json
|  |_Authentication.cs
|  |_Configuration.cs
|  |_Program.cs
|  |_ProtectedApiCallHelper.cs
|  |_PublicAppUsingUsernamePassword.cs
|  |_SiteInformation.cs
|  |_Startup.cs
|  |_SiteInformation.cs
|
|--ISARRHH.BusinessGraph (Class Library)
|  |_Dependencies
|  |_UserGraph.cs
|
|--Solution Items
   |_Dockerfile
   |_.dockerignore
```

EDIT2: More information

```
REPOSITORY                             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
isarrhh                                latest              67fc0628c921        13 minutes ago      268MB
```

according to this, the image was created succesfully apparently, but when i run it with

```
docker run -d -p 3001:80 ...
```

then i check with

```
docker container ls
```

i see no container running, also, when i check with the command you provided here

```
docker logs -t isachile
```

i get this:

```
MacBook: ISARRHH$ docker logs -t isachile
2019-07-31T18:49:22.553317346Z Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
2019-07-31T18:49:22.553390430Z   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
```

EDIT 3: SOLVED IT -- SORT OF...

i manage to run my docker by manually copy and pasting ever file on a different project, each file individually copy and paste in this second project, and each time creating the docker image, yes, a seriously horrible and tedious process, but it worked, although, we're not considering this solution anymore, since the process is too slow for our scrum project, we need to connect react native to our localhost api, i still need an answer for this

Answer (score 1):

So there's two things here, and neither necessarily indicates a problem with Docker or your Dockerfile.

1. Size is only 200-300MB

   That's about right. You haven't indicated whether you're using Windows or Linux containers, but in either case, most of the weight comes simply from the .NET Core runtime. The whole point of containers is that the host OS is shared (unlike a VM where every VM gets its own separate OS installation). The only things coming from the base OS image are user-specific files and directories. The main system components are proxied to the host operating system. Long and short, I don't know what you're expecting here in terms of size, but honestly 200-300MB is a bit on the *large* size for an image. It's possible in many cases to package ASP.NET Core app images down to as little as 25MB-30MB, though if you include the full runtime, it's generally going to be closer to your 200-300MB.
2. The container isn't running.

   All the means is that it exited. When the container is run, the entrypoint line will be called, which just starts up the ASP.NET Core app running in Kestrel. That of course runs `Program.Main`, since it's just a console app, after all. That in turn builds the web host and calls `Run`, which listens for TCP socket connections, keeping the app running, which therefore keeps the container running.

   If the container isn't running, then the app exited. That could happen for different reasons, but the most likely cause is that a runtime exception was thrown during the web host build phase (i.e. something in `Program` or `Startup` is throwing an exception). Try running something like:

   ```
   docker logs -t {container name}
   ```

   And you'll probably see a stacktrace and exception there. Fix the issue accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, i always thought docker was a sort of proxy, anyways, i still don't see the problem i'm getting, since my logs are showing nothing but this "Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:" also, can you check the project file structure i edited a few days ago? see if anything is wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: That's very odd. The error is what you get if you install the runtime only and then attempt to do things like `dotnet restore`, `dotnet build`, etc. Those commands required the SDK. However, based on your Dockerfile the build stages look correct. You're including the SDK for all the build parts and then including the runtime only in the final stage.

Comment: FWIW, it's a bit weird that your Dockerfile is in "Solution Items". It's probably not an issue, but that should really go in your project. Each project could conceivably be a different container. Right now, you just have one API app and a class library, but if you added another app like a Web UI, then you'd need a separate Dockerfile for that, and you wouldn't want both in the solution root.

Comment: actually, that solution items folder was created automatically when i dragged the dockerfile in the sln folder, also, if i move the dockerfile inside the api project, then, when i build the image, it shows me this error 
Step 1/16 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
 ---> 3af77ac73731
Step 2/16 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6901b54db948
Step 3/16 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 949a405f7446
Step 4/16 : COPY ISARRHH.sln ./
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder718989934/ISARRHH.sln: no such file or directory